# How do you count the frequency of a word in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 20000 rows and a column called XXX. XXX has string(VARCHAR2)(names with more than one word) in it and I want to find the first word in that name and display with a query if it occurs more than 30 times.
For example, if the first word of the word is *foo* and it occurs 30 times or *boo* occurs 40 times, then

```
Word       Count
foo         30
boo         40
```

the word can be anything. Only condition is frequency. I tried to solve it with INSTR, but I couldn't get it. 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is your database platform?

Comment: How you separate a word? Space or any other character?

Comment: Added `oracle` tag due to the mentioning of `varchar2`

Comment: What to do with `foobar`? Does it count as `foo`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is Oracle, separete with ''.

Comment: @user2097866: Can you give an example of a text and the outcome?

Comment: I meant foo and bar as different strings. It can be anything. I want to find the number occurrences.

Comment: ok let say the first word on the column is "greg", it occurs 10 times, so I don't show it. Second row, the first word is "mark", it searches the entire column and DBMS finds that it occurs 40 times then it will display it like;
Word     Count
mark      40

Comment: YOu sperate the word with space, it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your column values seperated by a delimiter like ',' or '.' or space  you can use a group by query like below

```
select count(*),substr(col,1,(instr(col,'.')-1) from tab group by  substr(col,1,(instr(col,'.')-1) order by 2;
```

This might help you [REGEXP](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

Comment: Hi Rock'em,
It works thanks a lot. I have only one question, how can I apply the query to only the first words? Let say, I am looking for word "Betrayed". I want to count the row consists "BETRAYED DISTURBING" because "Betrayed" appears as the first word but not the row "CHAPLIN BETRAYED" because "Betrayed" is the second word. At the moment, the query counts all the same words in the column. Thanks again. Big help

Comment: I got the solution I want. Thanks Rock'em